# How to bypass Certificate Authority for Local site?

Tags: certificate-authority, self-signed

We made a site which will be used only in local (is not publicity available). It supports https with self signed cert and key. Now, if I use the site - it says 'your connection to this site is not secure'. I know we need to buy certification from trusted CA. As site will be used only locally, is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: By locally, do you mean on the site is on an internal network, or that the site is only visible to same computer that's hosting it?

Comment: I mean, site is only accessible on the internal network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run proper HTTPS on an Internal Network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121163), [Encrypting local HTTP traffic using a self-signed certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27898), [Obtaining an SSL certificate for a local web application](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158074), [How to force browser to trust a self-signed cert](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/162901), [Adding self signed certificate to trusted store](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36913) and probably even more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the Root-CA which was used to sign the self signed Certificate into your trusted certificate store.
It depends on your OS how to do this